# DOM element temporarily displaying on screen before being removed from page using jQuery's .remove() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `.remove()` jQuery method to remove an element from the page on page load. For example:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( '.element').remove();
    // More code...
});
```

The element flashes on screen temporarily and is then removed once the page is loaded. How can I ensure `.element` does not flash on screen? I'd like it to be removed instantly (before the user has the chance to see it)?

I've tried doing the following but that has no effect:

```
jQuery( '.element').remove();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    // More code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because first of all your page will be rendered and when your DOM is fully rendered then `document.ready` will fire and then code written inside `document.ready` will run and with jquery specific html will be removed from page so for flicker of a time the html which you want to remove will appear .

I m not sure but i think hiding a element will be somewhat faster then removing it so you can do as :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $( '.element').hide();
  // More code...
});
```

OR

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $( '.element').css('display','none');
  // More code...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the flickering looks really unprofessional so I'd like to find a solution. So any idea how I can approach the problem?

Comment: @henrywright...you can do this thing with javascript instead because javascript is somewhat more faster than jquery...

Comment: These examples still require the page loads first, which in turn causes the element to display briefly on screen

Comment: @henrywright...but this could be the best possible solution as far as my knowledge goes...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest applying `display: none;` to the .element's css as probably the simplest way to hide the element straight away.

Comment: If he could change the HTML or CSS, he probably wouldn't need to remove it with jQuery.

Comment: However he hasn't expressly said he can't use CSS, he might just not have thought of it. But you have a fair point.

Comment: `display: none` could work but I need `.element` to be visible if JavaScript is disabled. If JS is disabled and I use `display: none` nothing is shown on screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete a dom node before dom has been parsed.use `<noscript></noscript>` if you are not using XHTML.

Comment: How does Google interpret links inside `<noscript>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put on the `head` tag this code:

```
<script>
  $( '.parent_class' ).on('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function( el ) {
    if ( $( '.element').length ) {
      $( '.element' ).remove();
    }
  }, false);
<script>
```

<strike>Note: This is very costly operation and may be not cross-browser one.</strike>

Comment: Thanks Sergiy, although I do need a cross-browser solution and would rather not sacrifice performance slightly.

Comment: Please try an updated code: I added IE's `propertychange` and watching only target element's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Add a body class `no-js` to all pages.

Then, if JS is enabled, the following will execute:

```
if ( $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'no-js' ) )
    $( 'body' ).attr( 'class', $( 'body' ).attr( 'class' ).replace( /no-js/, 'js' ) );
```

Then you can simply style your page elements like this for people with JS disabled

```
body.no-js {
    // Some CSS
}
```

So with reference to my question, I can do this

```
.pagination {
    display: none;
}

body.no-js .pagination {
    display: block;
}
```

**Note:** The idea is taken from how [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org) does things.